# How to handle Rust lifetimes for C functions that follow the iterator pattern?

Tags: c, rust

I have a C API that I want to wrap with Rust. Most of the time it just works, but I've come to an issue with an iterator-pattern in C as demoed in the example below:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ExampleIter {
  const char **chain;
  char *current;
};

bool example_iter_next(struct ExampleIter *iter) {
  free(iter->current);
  if (iter->chain[0] == NULL) {
        iter->current = NULL;
    return false;
  }
  iter->current = strdup(iter->chain[0]);
  iter->chain++;
  return true;
}

int main(void) {
  const char *chain[] = {"Hello", "World", "!", NULL};
    struct ExampleIter iter = {.chain = chain, .current = NULL};
    while (example_iter_next(&iter)) {
        printf("%s\n", iter.current);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

It's not the exact example, but it illustrates the issue. As you can see, the pointer `char *current` is invalidated by each call of `example_iter_next`.

If I implement an `std::iter::Iterator` for this type, how do I handle that the `char *current` pointer is invalid after `example_iter_next` is called?

Answer (score 3):

Frankly what I'd do is rewrite the API to be less wonky: instead of storing `current` in the iterator you could just return it directly, and return `null` in the terminal case. To me this is a strictly more convenient interface, and it works correctly with Rust's semantics (it's essentially a desugared [`Cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Cloned.html)). Hell, you don't even need to copy anything, just return `iter->chain[0]` directly, and you have what's essentially [a slice iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html).

Alternatively if you don't want to change the structure of the iterator you could have the consumer *move* `iter->current` (copy the pointer and set it to null), this way the `free(iter->current)` becomes a no-op, and the caller is in charge of managing the pointer formerly known as current `current` which works fine.

But if you're *really* intent on these iterator semantics and on exposing them to rust, Generic Associated Types were stabilised in 1.65 (a bit less than a year ago), and [the type use case is a borrowing iterator](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1598-generic_associated_types.html). Which is exactly what you have here.

So while you would not be able to implement `Iterator`, and there is currently no GAT-iterator sugar, you would be able to express an iterator-like interface which is still familiar because it's how e.g. streams tend to be used.